# error textBox3 ACCESSED FROM A THREAD OTHER THAN THE THREAD IT WAS CREATED ON while executing Plinq query

Tags: c#, plinq

i have a method in another class that select all the lines that contains given char from textbox2,and print it to textbox3 on button_click but i'm having this error (textBox3 ACCESSED FROM A THREAD OTHER THAN THE THREAD IT WAS CREATED ON).

```
public void plinq()
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>(textBox2.Lines);
        List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            if (textBox3.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox3.Invoke(new Action(plinq));
            }
            else
            {
                lines.AsParallel().ForAll(K =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < K.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (lines[i].Contains(textBox4.Text))
                        {
                            lines2.Add(lines[i]);
                        }  
                    }
                    textBox3.Lines = lines2.ToArray();
                }); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image]

and her is the code of the button where i am calling the method

```
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Text = "";
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        worker = new Worker(n, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4);
        Thread thread = new Thread(worker.plinq);
        sw.Start();
        thread.Start();
        //worker.plinq();
        sw.Stop();
        button6.Text = Convert.ToString(sw.Elapsed);
        sw.Reset();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited duplicate is pretty old.  It's not inaccurate - but it pre-dates PLINQ.

Look here:

> [**MS Documentation: Potential pitfalls with PLINQ**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-with-plinq)
>
> **Avoid calls to non-thread-safe methods**
>
> Writing to non-thread-safe instance methods from a PLINQ query can
>   lead to data corruption which may or may not go undetected in your
>   program. It can also lead to exceptions. In the following example,
>   multiple threads would be attempting to call the FileStream.Write
>   method simultaneously, which is not supported by the class.
>
> ...
>
> **Prefer ForAll to ForEach when it is possible**
>
> Although PLINQ executes a query on multiple threads, if you consume
>   the results in a foreach loop (For Each in Visual Basic), then the
>   query results must be merged back into one thread and accessed
>   serially by the enumerator. In some cases, this is unavoidable;
>   however, whenever possible, use the ForAll method to enable each
>   thread to output its own results, for example, by writing to a
>   thread-safe collection such as
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag.
>
> The same issue applies to Parallel.ForEach. In other words,
>   source.AsParallel().Where().ForAll(...) should be strongly preferred
>   to Parallel.ForEach(source.AsParallel().Where(), ...).
>
> ...
>
> **Be aware of thread affinity issues**
>
> Some technologies, for example, COM interoperability for
>   Single-Threaded Apartment (STA) components, Windows Forms, and Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF), impose thread affinity restrictions
>   that require code to run on a specific thread. For example, in both
>   Windows Forms and WPF, a control can only be accessed on the thread on
>   which it was created. If you try to access the shared state of a
>   Windows Forms control in a PLINQ query, an exception is raised if you
>   are running in the debugger. (This setting can be turned off.)
>   However, if your query is consumed on the UI thread, then you can
>   access the control from the foreach loop that enumerates the query
>   results because that code executes on just one thread.
>
> ...

Please update your post:

Q1: Exactly which line is the error occurring on?

Q2: Is it occurring in the debugger, outside of the debugger, or both?

Q3: Did refactoring your code with any of the suggestions in the link help?

Q4: Does refactoring your code such that all modifications to "TextBox3" occur *OUTSIDE* of PLinq (and occur *ONLY* on the UI thread) help?

Comment: first i am sorry ,but i t's my first time dealing with threads and Plinq ,that's why i am confused.to answer your questions:Q1:the error occurred at the line (textBox3.Lines = lines2.ToArray();) but visual studio highlight all the lines inside of AsParallel.ForAll loop.Q2 both.Q3: no.Q4: when i but TextBox3 outside the ForAll loop i don't get the results that i want.

Comment: I doubt "System.InvalidOperationException" is the result you want,either ;)  You simply *shouldn't* try updating TextBox3 (which executes on the UI thread) from inside of a parallel "ForAll()" loop.  There's no *NEED* to parallelize the operation anyway!  Just refactor your code - it's as simple as that :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help,i did eventuality refactor my code ,it's the best and simplest solution as you said